# Views gets automatically updated in SQL sever?

Tags: sql-server

I have a question. I have updated many tables in the database. There exists Views on top of those tables which I have updated. So if I have updated the original Tables, will the Views get updated as well?
Please help me understanding this.

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: *Short answer:* It depends. **Detailed answer:** If your views do not have filters in place (by using some `WHERE` clauses) to remove the data you just updated or inserted then it will show up. Otherwise, it won't.

Comment: Add/Edit/Delete data YES...  Structural changes to the tables NO.

Comment: Ok.. thank you for clarifying.

Comment: A view is essentially a saved filter to underlying tables that is queried against like a table. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views

Comment: Good to know about this. Thanks!

Comment: Also be careful. Changing the order of columns without updating the view can lead to some interesting results if you are using select * in your view. But then if your are using select * in your views you have many other major issues when you change the schema. yet another reason to avoid using select *

Answer (score 0):

YES.

If the base table is updated with data then the view gets the updated data. but if there are any new columns added to the base table then the view need to be refreshed.

Comment: A view does not have to represent one base table. It can be the result of many tables or even just static data or other views.

Comment: Yes you are right.. In my answer i mentioned base table but the user may have n number of tables.. Logic is the same.